# Disable clicks on entire RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, view, android-recyclerview

I want to **disable clicks on the entire** `RecyclerView` once an item of it is clicked and enable it back again after suppose 500 milis.

The idea is just to **prevent multiple rapid clicks** on the items of the RecyclerView items. For example, some one may quickly tap on 3 items and all of them will get triggered.

I have tried `setEnabled(false)` and `setClickable(false)` but both of them doesn't work alone or when used together.

Comment: Can you share the code where you set item click listener in recyclerview.

Answer (score 5):

May be you have to disable all the children of the RecyclerView.
You can do it like this:

```
private static void setViewAndChildrenEnabled(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            setViewAndChildrenDisabled(child, enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

Where parameter `view` is your RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

Use RxJava throttlefirst operator, pretty easy.